# Extracting Subtitles from mkv using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, subtitle

So I'm trying to extract the subtitles and their format (how they look) and also trying to implement them into another mkv of the same video. Long story short, I'm trying to get the nice looking subtitles that follow the colour of their background

[image]

and their lovely colours

[image]

So when I use FFmpeg to check the streams and how I would map them and whatot and then this shows up

[image]

There are up to 40 sum streams all to get the nice looking subtitles. So, how would I get all those out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To extract all those fonts:

```
ffmpeg -dump_attachment:t "" -i input.mkv
```

(ffmpeg will spit out an error but the fonts will be extracted)

To copy subtitles and fonts to new MKV

```
ffmpeg -i new.mp4 -i old.mkv -c copy -map 0 -map 1:s -map 1:t new.mkv
```

Comment: This works with no problems other than that the subtitles are off by like .7 seconds. I'm using this to take subtitles from the same video (just a different format) and putting them into this video. Both videos are the same episode, but the one I'm extracting them from has an extra 10 seconds towards the end of the video.